# IE7 jQuery .clone and .serialize

Tags: jquery, forms, asp.net-mvc-3, serialization, internet-explorer-7

I have a strange bug, this is my code

```
var form = $("form").clone();
hiddenNodes.clone().appendTo(form);
parameters = form.serialize();
```

I have some checkboxes in this  form and some other inputs, If a checkbox is not checked and I check it, the parameters string will contain the correct value for that checkbox. However if I want to uncheck the checkbox the parameters string will always be true (The value that the checkbox had initially from reponse)... It works in Firefox...

**edit: Rhe below is not relevant but I keep it for history**

I use MVC3 and MVC3 renders two inputs for checkboxes, one checkbox and one hidden, this is because when you submit a form it only submits the checked boxes. The hidden field always have value false, so when the check the checkbox you will get two inputs with the same name (the first one with value true and the other one with value false) but MVC model binder only takes the first one. When the checkbox is unchecked it will only send the hidden field with value false and the binder will bind to that.

But this is when you are doing full submits, im doing an ajax post, to get the form data i do a jquery serialize form, in Firefox serialize takes the first occurrence of each input and thats why it works in firefox. IE7 includes both, and since the value for the checkbox is true the modelbinder will bind to that.. Are there any clean solution around this? 
I could remove all unchecked checkboxes before serializaing, is that the best way

**edit2: Read from here**

form.clone() in IE7 will always return the HTML as it looked when it came from the server, so if the checkbox was checked from server it will be checked when you do form.clone(). I need to clone it because I use ajax and cant destroy the markup...

**edit3: This gets crazier**
The edit2 is only true when the checkbox is checked from server, in this case the clone will always be checked doesnt matter if you have unchecked... But if the checkbox was unchecked from server and you check it you will get a checked box in the cloned form.

edit: **This fixes the problem**

After cloneNode i need to have these lines to add the old innerHtml to the node
if (jQuery.browser.msie && (jQuery.browser.version <= 7))
            clone.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML;

The problem is that changing in the jQuery core API is never a good solution its a known fix so for some reason the jQuery team do not wanna fix it. I tried to override the cloneNode method on the Element and add the code there, worked in FF but not in IE, I also tried to override the clone method in jQuery that part worked, but the underlying clone code uses methods that I can not find a way to access outside of jQuery....

If anyone have a good way of adding above lines of code to jQuery without changing in actual api please let me know

Comment: can you post the html code, I think, you may have made a mistake there.

Comment: Have you checked in the IE dev tools what happens? I found older versions of IE to be highly nit-picky when inserting jQuery created elements into the DOM as it thinks they are "not valid".

Answer (score 1):

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6486 shows some info about a bugreport on the topic.

You can also try adding the following code and make sure it runs before you apply the .clone:

```
document.getElementById('id').onclick = function() { 
  var broken = document.getElementById('id'); 
  if (broken.checked) broken.setAttribute('checked','checked'); 
  else broken.removeAttribute('checked'); 
};
```

It might work since IE has some know issues with inner-/outerHTML.

Comment: Yeah, I found that one yesterday but id didnt help, I had to change in the jQuery core to get it to work, but that is not a liable solution so I have to find something else, I tried to overwrite the cloneNode method on the element level, didnt work.. See my edit for the code